# How to run a Drush command in interactive mode

Tags: 6, drush

I want Drush to actively output messages instead of putting them into a buffer and then outputting them when it is done running. Now Drush has an interactive mode that I think will do this. However I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

I can modify either Drush or my Drupal module (that contains Drush commands) to do this. I just need to know what to do to accomplish this.

I am running Drush 4.4 against Drupal 6.22.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: never heard of 'interactive mode'. just checked http://drush.ws, are you sure there is such a thing? I'd love if there was.

Comment: Drush 4.4, file: /includes/backend.inc, line 394

Comment: Ref: http://drupal.org/node/1058874 - Based on this I could just hack drush to set this, but I would like to just be able to pass the param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'interactive' flag in Drush backend invoke is only used when Drush is going to programatically call another Drush command.  In this instance, the interactive flag tells Drush to call the subcommand in a way that will allow user input.

The issue you reference above (drupal.org/node/1058874) is now standard in Drush 5. If you upgrade, you should find that Drush does a better job at showing incremental progress in some situations. Of course, there are also still some commands where Drush must first compose all of the output, then format it in a table, then output it.  In these cases, the output will always be buffered.

Comment: I kinda gave up on this awhile ago for what I was doing. But I found another solution for it. So that is fine.